# Get Text of clicked link from a function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to start off by saying I'm not an expert, maybe not even an intermediate, user of jQuery and any and all help is appreciated.

Here is a simulation of my little problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/c897enhy/

```
<a id="someRandomID_hypNotifSentTo_0" class="NotifSent2" href = "#">
    this is the text i want to get
</a>
<br>
<a id="someRandomID_hypNotifSentTo_0" class="NotifSent2" href = "#">
    this is the text i want to get 2
</a>
<br>
<a id="someRandomID_hypNotifSentTo_0" class="NotifSent2" href = "#">
    this is the text i want to get 3
</a>


if ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a[id*='_hypNotifSentTo_']").live("click", function ($e) {

            // Will post list of recipients to be removed from the file
            var x = $(this).text();
            alert(x);
            AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients("restult");
        });

         function AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients(result) {
             alert("asdf");
             var x = $('#NotifSent2').toString();
             alert(x);
             var x = $(this).text();
             alert(x);

             var recipients = $(this).text();
             alert("1");
             var recipientArr = recipients.split(',');
         }
       });
}
```

While, I am able to get the text of the active link from the "click" event, I am unable to do so from my second function.

The way the application works, is that the first function call ajax c# file, which then returns a success into the second jquery function with some results from c#.

I need to compare the results that are returned from the c# to what is inside the clicked hyperlink, but am unable to get the clicked text from within that "AjaxSuccess" function.

Comment: `var x = $('#NotifSent2').toString(); var x = $(this).text();` this makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing the the context of $(this) when you're in the Ajax function ($(this) will no longer refer to the clicked link). Try adding a variable that you can store the context in, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $that;
        $("a[id*='_hypNotifSentTo_']").live("click", function ($e) {

            // Will post list of recipients to be removed from the file
            $that = $(this);
 var x = $that.text();
            alert(x);
            AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients("restult");
        });

         function AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients(result) {
alert("asdf");
             //var x = $('#NotifSent2').toString();
              //alert(x);
            var x = $that.text();
            alert(x);

            var recipients = $(this).text();
            alert("1");
            var recipientArr = recipients.split(',');
         }
       });
```

Comment: thank you! i'll test some more, but it looks like it's working!

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside the `AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients` refers to the Widow object and not the anchor tag that was clicked.

Just send the reference of anchor tag from click event to the second function like this

```
AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients("restult", $(this));
```

Use it as context like this

```
function AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients(result, context) { // <--- context refers to the anchor tag
  alert("asdf");
  var x = $('.NotifSent2').text();
  alert(x);
  var x = context.text();
  alert(x);
  var recipients = context.text();
  alert("1");
  var recipientArr = recipients.split(',');
}
```

Comment: My heartfelt sympathy for the widow and the family members! ;)

Comment: @Andreas: Haha exactly ! :D Not just that, Window is also heavily abused.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

> The **call()** method calls a function with a given *this* value and
>   arguments provided individually.

Change:

`AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients("restult");`

To:

`AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients.call(this, "restult");`

Doing so will pass the correct *this* value to your function.

Comment: Some of the other answers suggest passing in `this` or `$(this)` as an additional parameter.  Using `call` accomplishes a similar effect but has the advantage of not needing to worry about additional parameters or changing the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not able to access data via this `$('#NotifSent2')` selector as the `#` selector is JQuery syntax for finding an ID on the page, whereas your elements are constructed with `class="NotifSent2"`.

If you wish to access a variable from a different function, you must ensure that the variable is within the correct scope.

Since your AJAX call and `AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients()` function are within the same scope, you do not have access to $(this) across the two.

Simply pass the variable you wish to use to your function, as $(this) `AjaxSuccessPopulateRecipients("restult", $(this));`